# Click function within Hover function disables hover function onced clicked

Tags: jquery, for-loop, click, hover, nested-function

Hey I have a hover function that populates list items within an unordered list using a for loop.  Once the list items are generated I need them to have a click function that corresponds to the number at the end of their id's.

I got the click function to work for the populated list items but the problem is that once a list item is clicked it disables the hover function.

Any ideas for keeping the hover function working after the list items are clicked?

```
$(".changeProductWrapper").hover(function(){

for (var x=5; x>0; x--) {

    otherProductId = "#productChoice" + x;

        if (typeof otherProducts === 'undefined') {

            otherProducts = '<li class="productChoice" id="'+otherProductId+'">' + $(otherProductId).html() + '</li>';
        }

        else {

            otherProducts = '<li class="productChoice" id="'+otherProductId+'">' + $(otherProductId).html() + '</li>' + otherProducts;

        };

};

$(".productChoice").click(function(){

    // function

});

});
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't provide enough information to show what's going on. The best way to help people answer is to post a full demo of the problem on http://jsfiddle.net . To start, though, maybe try moving the `$(".productChoice").click` declaration out of the `$(".changeProductWrapper").hover` function body?

Comment: Also when I put the $(".productChoice").click function outside of the hover it doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Alright here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LuZUm/10/    --- You'll see that the hover function no longer works for a product after it's been swapped for another one